# Is there any reason to use HTTP header authorization to send JWT token instead of cookie?

Tags: cookies, jwt, http-headers, authorization

**Is there any reason to use HTTP header authorization to send JWT token?**

I was confused using authorization header and cookie.

If I use the cookie,
Server will send JWT token in cookie. (Client side will be stored in cookie).

If I use the authorization header, Server will send JWT token through header and client side will store token in local storage.

I guess both can be vulnerable to security.
I’ve checked several posts, but only said that both methods are dangerous.

Please help me to understand this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From the API's point of view, it might be simpler to handle an authorization header instead of a cookie header. The latter might contain numerous cookies, you then have to parse all of them and find the required header.

On the client-side using tokens instead of cookies will work better for cross-domain requests. In some cases, third-party cookies might get dropped.

Still, as Tore pointed out, it's safer to avoid storing tokens in the browser. You can have a look at the [Token Handler pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/the-token-handler-pattern/) that we've created at Curity to learn about the possibilities of using a BFF.

Comment: Agree with the API point of view. Encountered a authorization header vs cookie situation in a recent project where it was much easier to work with authorization header. But when it comes to saving tokens for longer duration, cookie seems to be a better pick.

Answer (score 1):

Using the authorization header is slightly safer compared to cookies, because you are less vulnerable to CSRF attacks. However, in both cases you are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Ideally, you should not store tokens at all in the browser and instead look at using the BFF pattern as described in this video:

[alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=2564s)

Comment: If the cookie has the `SameSite` and `HttpOnly` attributes set, doesn't that mitigate both XSS and CSRF? A cookie containing an auth token can't be retrieved or reflected if the JavaScript runtime can't access it and cookies won't be sent from spoofed sites or redirects if `SameSite` is set to `strict`.

Comment: If the cookie has HttpOnly, SameSite=Strict, and Secure, then it is the same as a session cookie, and why then store the JWT as a cookie? JWT's are not typically encrypted either, so anyone can peek inside the content. While a session cookie is typically encrypted using an encryption key. Also, JWT's can be quite big, so that would also mean that you have large cookies and a cookie can only be about max 4000 bytes each.